# Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to String(Generics)

Tags: java, generics

Hi I am playing with generics a suddenly found a issue where i am getting compile time error :

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to String

```
import java.util.*;

public class A<T> {
    private final T first;

    public A(T first) {
        this.first = first;

    }
    public List<String> stringList() {
        return Arrays.asList(String.valueOf(first));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A p = new A<Object>("TEST");
        for (String s : p.stringList())
            System.out.print(s + " ");
    }
}
```

I am unable to understand this behavior as String is Object and compiler should understand that, can someone explain this?

Comment: Why it is marked as duplicate....its not a bug..:(

Comment: Using a raw type in the type declaration makes all generics in the type raw, even if they are unrelated to the omitted type constraint.

Comment: I think the relevant section from the linked question is titled "**A raw type is the erasure of that type**" which shows what looks like a very similar example

Comment: Use this to make it compile: `A<Object> p = new A<>("TEST");`

Comment: @RobinTopper---It is working fine thanks could you please explain me why it is compiling now

Comment: ShowStopper - Because declaring it properly means you're not using a raw type `A` anymore.

Comment: @AndyTurner: So by using the raw type `A`, it means that `stringList`'s return type is just `List` from the compiler's perspective, not `List<String>`, is that correct?

Comment: So what I understand is compiler interprets the program as if this method returned the raw typeList.
While List<String> implements the parameterized type Iterable<String>, List implements the raw type Iterable. Where Iterable<String> has an iterator method that returns the parameterized type , Iterable has an iterator method that returns the raw type Iterator. Where the next method
of Iterator<String>returns String, the next method of Iterator returns Object. Therefore, iterating overp.stringList() requires a loop variable of type Object, which explains the compiler's error message

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes.

Comment: @AndyTurner Thanks. I added that other dupe, btw.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder--Is it really a duplicate ...??

Comment: Yes, it is a duplicate.

Comment: okies...:( by the way thanks guys

Comment: @ShowStopper: Yes, of both of those. The central issue is that by just using `A p` instead of `A<Object> p`, **all** generic type parameters for `p` are erased entirely. So it's as though your `stringList` were declared `List stringList()` (the raw type `List`). So `for (String s : p.stringList())` is asking to use `Object` (the element type of the raw type `List`) as a `String`. You can't do that implicitly.